# BaseExpandableListAdapter convertview returns old view from getChildView()

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

I have confusion BaseExpandableListAdapter concept, explained my problem below.

**Expectation:**

For example I have two groups , each group holds different layout as child like below

- **Group1**-ReceivedRequest:

  child1 - from Layout1

  child2 - from Layout1
- **Group2**-ReceivedSent:

  child1 - from Layout2

  child2 - from Layout2

**Problem**:

When I click **Group1** first and then **Group2** its work perfect (i.e. convertview is null when calling for first time on respective group so its inflating right way),

But when I click **Group2** first and then **Group1** its still returning old **Group2** view ...(i.e convertview should be null but its returning old view )

Kindly route me where is the issue..
I found exact ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594599/why-does-expandablelistview-change-childview-settings-android) on Stackoverflow but there is no solution yet

**Below is my code**

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        SingleRow singleRow = new SingleRow();
        RequestInfo Req_child = (RequestInfo) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        String type = Req_child.requestertype;
        if(convertView==null) {

            switch (type)
            {
                case RequestInfo.REQ_RECEIVED_ACCOUNT:

                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_reqlist_acctrcvd, null);
                    convertView.setTag( singleRow);
                    break;

                case RequestInfo.REQ_SENTACCOUNT:

                    LayoutInflater infalInflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater1.inflate(R.layout.row_reqlist_acctsent, null);
                    convertView.setTag(singleRow);
                    break;
                    }
        }

        singleRow = (SingleRow) convertView.getTag();
        switch (type)
        {
            case RequestInfo.REQ_RECEIVED_ACCOUNT:
                singleRow.tvUsername_req_rcd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_username);
                singleRow.tvNickName_req_rcd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_nickname);
                singleRow.im_gender_req_rcd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_profpic);
                singleRow.btAcceptReq = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_accpt);
                singleRow.btRjctReq = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_rjct);

                singleRow.tvUsername_req_rcd.setText(Req_child.requesterUsername);
                singleRow.tvNickName_req_rcd.setText(Req_child.requesterNickName);
                singleRow.im_gender_req_rcd.setImageBitmap(Req_child.requestergender.equals("Male") ? rmale_pic : rfemale_pic);
                Log.i("Expand", "your child username is " + Req_child.requesterUsername);

            break;

            case RequestInfo.REQ_SENTACCOUNT:
                singleRow.tvUsername_req_sent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_username);
                singleRow.tvNickName_req_sent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_nickname);
                singleRow.im_gender_req_sent = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_profpic);
                singleRow.btReqSent = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_btn_sent_reqaccts);

                singleRow.tvUsername_req_sent.setText(Req_child.requesterUsername);
                singleRow.tvNickName_req_sent.setText(Req_child.requesterNickName);
                singleRow.im_gender_req_sent.setImageBitmap(Req_child.requestergender.equals("Male") ? rmale_pic : rfemale_pic);
                Log.i("Expand", "your child username is " + Req_child.requesterUsername);

        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answering my own question so that it will help others, I suppose to override the method manually **getChildTypeCount()**  and **getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)** incase you have different child layout, Find my below updated code.

```
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SingleRow singleRow = null;
    RequestInfo Req_child = childtems.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    String type = Req_child.requestertype;
    if(convertView==null ) {
        switch (type)
        {
            case RequestInfo.REQ_RECEIVED_ACCOUNT:
                 singleRow = new SingleRow();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_reqlist_acctrcvd, null);
                    singleRow.tvUsername_req_rcd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_username);
                    singleRow.tvNickName_req_rcd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_nickname);
                    singleRow.im_gender_req_rcd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_profpic);
                    singleRow.btAcceptReq = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_accpt);
                    singleRow.btRjctReq = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_rcvd_rjct);
                    convertView.setTag(singleRow);
                break;

            case RequestInfo.REQ_SENTACCOUNT:
                 singleRow = new SingleRow();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_reqlist_acctsent, null);
                    singleRow.tvUsername_req_sent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_username);
                    singleRow.tvNickName_req_sent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_nickname);
                    singleRow.im_gender_req_sent = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_reqaccts_sent_profpic);
                    singleRow.btReqSent = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rw_btn_sent_reqaccts);
                    convertView.setTag(singleRow);
                break;
                }
    }
    else
    {
        singleRow = (SingleRow) convertView.getTag();
    }

    switch (type)
    {
        case RequestInfo.REQ_RECEIVED_ACCOUNT:
            singleRow.tvUsername_req_rcd.setText(Req_child.requesterUsername);
            singleRow.tvNickName_req_rcd.setText(Req_child.requesterNickName);
            singleRow.im_gender_req_rcd.setImageBitmap(Req_child.requestergender.equals("Male") ? rmale_pic : rfemale_pic);
        break;

        case RequestInfo.REQ_SENTACCOUNT:
            singleRow.tvUsername_req_sent.setText(Req_child.requesterUsername);
            singleRow.tvNickName_req_sent.setText(Req_child.requesterNickName);
            singleRow.im_gender_req_sent.setImageBitmap(Req_child.requestergender.equals("Male") ? rmale_pic : rfemale_pic);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```